# A simple issue with contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is probably something quite simple, but I can't get my head around this.
Consider the following holomophic funtion : $$f(z)=1-|z|^2$$
**This function is zero all along the unit circle C**.

So I would say that  for every complex number $a$ within the open unit disc, $$\int_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz=0$$

But according to Cauchy's Integral formula, that would mean that $f$ is $0$ everywhere inside the open unit disc, which is obviously false.

Am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: $f$ is not holomorphic

Comment: Why isn't $f$ holomorphic ? Sorry if this is very basic, I am not familiar at all with complex analysis

Comment: what is $f'(z)$?

Comment: Oh you're right, $f'$ isn't differentiable. Thank you

Comment: Not exactly, try to use the Cauchy Riemann equations to see why it is not holomorphic on an open set containing the unit circle.

Comment: $f$ is not complex differentiable but it is real analytic as it is $1-x^2-y^2$ so is a real analytic polynomial but not a complex analytic polynomial; one has to be careful and distinguish the notions of complex differentiability vs real differentiability

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not holomorphic. Try to think what it series might be.

More formally, zeros of a holomorphic function are isolated, which is not the case with your function.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the zeros either